# Открытие/закрытие balloon при ховере и его позиционирование

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Cделал карту участков (с помощью полигонов), и при ховере открывается баллун с инфой об участке, но баллун позиционируется не правильно.

Есть кейс когда ты пытаешься навести курсор на баллун (допустим, нажать кнопку) и ховер срабатывает на другом участке, соответственно отрывается другой баллун а старый закрывается.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы баллун позиционировался в плотную к участку?

Код:

```
(function () {

for (let i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {

let num = areas[i]['number'];

let coords = areas[i]['coords'];

let status = areas[i]['status'];

let price = areas[i]['price'];

let area = areas[i]['area'];

let opacity = 0.5;

let newCoords = new Array();

for (let q = 0; q < coords.length; q++) {

let item = [];

item.push(coords[q]['latitude']);

item.push(coords[q]['longtitude']);

newCoords.push(item);

}

if (status == 0) {

status = statusFree;

opacity = 1;

} else if (status == 1) {

status = statusSold;

} else {

status = statusReserved;

}

let Land = new ymaps.Polygon([

newCoords

], {

balloonContent: descriptionFormation(status, num, area, price),

balloonAutoPan: false,

}, {

fillColor: status,

fillOpacity: opacity,

zIndex: 1,

zIndexHover: 1,

});

mapLand.geoObjects.add(Land);

mapLand.options.set('balloonAutoPan', false);

Land.events.add('mouseenter', function () {

Land.balloon.open();

});

}

function descriptionFormation(status, num, area, price, house) {

if (status == statusFree) {

if (house == true) {

let tmp = '<div class="ymap-content">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__number">Участок №<span>' + num + '</span></div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area-title">Площать</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area-value">' + area + '</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__buildings">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__buildings-title">Постройки</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__buildings-value">' + house + '</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__status ymap-content__status_green">Свободен</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__price">'+ price * 1000 +'</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__button"></div>';

tmp += '</div>';

return tmp;

}

else{

let tmp = '<div class="ymap-content">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__number">Участок №<span>' + num + '</span></div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area-title">Площать участка</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__area-value">' + area + ' сот.</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__status ymap-content__status_green">Свободен</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__price">' + price * 1000 + ' рублей</div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__button">Оставить заявку</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

return tmp;

}

}

else if (status == statusReserved) {

let tmp = '<div class="ymap-content">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__number">Участок №<span>' + num + '</span></div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__status ymap-content__status_yellow">Забронирован</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

return tmp;

}

else if (status == statusSold) {

let tmp = '<div class="ymap-content">';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__number">Участок №<span>' + num + '</span></div>';

tmp += '<div class="ymap-content__status ymap-content__status_red">Продан</div>';

tmp += '</div>';

return tmp;

}

}

$('body').on('click', '.ymap-content__button', function () {

clickOnPolygon();

});

function clickOnPolygon() {

$('.modal-window_contacts').addClass('modal-window_display');

setTimeout(function () {

$('.modal-window_contacts').addClass('modal-window_show');

}, 10);

}

})();
```

Comment: Соберите, пожалуйста, пример с объектами, не до конца понятно какое позиционирование вы называете неправильным. Балун открывается на позиции курсора. Что значит "позиционирование вплотную"?

Comment: Без рабочего примера не понятно в чем проблема.